# Can I make a computed string type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types

For example:

```
type EventName = "abort" | "afterprint" | "animationend"; //html event names.
type EventListenerPropertyName = "on" + EventName;
```

I want to create an `EventListenerPropertyName` from `EventName` (like this: `"on" + "click" => "onclick"`), but TypeScript looks like it doesn't support plus operator between types. How can I make it work?

Comment: You would need operator overloading to support this, which TypeScript doesn't support.

Comment: Discussed at length in [this ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12940) and linked discussions there.

Comment: @AaronBrager Then, can I concat two string types in other way?

Comment: Use `EventName`, and compute the property name when required.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579

Answer (score 0):

You can't but you can do it differently. I always use for such - tuple types. Consider:

```
type EventName = "abort" | "afterprint" | "animationend"; //html event names.
type EventListenerPropertyName = ["on" , EventName];

// example value
const x: EventListenerPropertyName = ['on', 'abort']
```

What you have is some kind of join of two types as you would in a form of string concatenation. We can also go further and introduce some generic types and value constructors. Consider:

```
type EventName = "abort" | "afterprint" | "animationend"; //html event names.
type EventListenerPropertyName<T extends EventName>  = ["on", T];

// value constructor
const makeEventListenerPropertyName = <T extends EventName>(a: T): EventListenerPropertyName<T> => ["on", a];
// parser to string
const eventListenerPropertyNameStr = <T extends EventListenerPropertyName<any>>(a: T): string => a[0] + a[1];

const x = makeEventListenerPropertyName('abort'); // x is ['on', 'abort']
const y = eventListenerPropertyNameStr(x); // y is onabort
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript 4.1 now supports [template literal string types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types), so you can do:

```js
type EventName = "abort" | "afterprint" | "animationend"; //html event names.
type EventListenerPropertyName = `on${EventName}`;
```

If you want to capitalize the first letter of each event, so that you have something like `onAbort`, you can use `Capitalize` from the builtin [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html)

```js
type EventListenerPropertyName = `on${Capitalize<EventName>}`;
```